# On bitbucket - how to remove a reviewer name?

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I made a lot of pull request, and some of them were approved disapproved by some reviewers.

How do I delete the history of my reviewers so they will not be suggested again under 'Recent'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitbucket hasn't implemented a way to clear the Recent reviewers list yet. Their only suggested option is to change the 'Default Reviewers' of the project.